# Can't exploit stack overflow

Tags: c, buffer

I'm learning buffer overflows, and I have a problem with exploiting a stack based buffer overflow. 
Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(){
    printf("asd");
}
main(){
    char buf[10];
    scanf("%s", &buf);
}
```

I'm overwriting first 14 bytes with A's(the buffer and the old EIP address). My goal is to execute the func function, or to change the EIP with it's address. But I'm always getting illegal instruction. I have check the HEX address of the function; I have written them in reverse order and they are correct.

Comment: Can you post the operating system/version, hardware platform, and the input you are using?

Comment: Kali linux i386, CPU Intel Core I3, DDR2 RAM, I don't get what you mean with input. I'm using terminal, input from keyboard, it should be stdin.

Comment: Have you tried with more than 14 bytes of input?

Comment: I have tried 14bytes + payload(the func address) and 28 bytes + payload.

Comment: You've proven that you are actually exploiting this since you crashed the program.  Taking advantage of it and not making it crash is an entirely different ballgame and not generally possible anymore thanks to the [NX bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_execute)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the compiled code in assembler e.g.
your main() may look like:

```
    char buf[10];
    scanf("%s", &buf);
00D7B938  mov         esi,esp  
00D7B93A  lea         eax,[ebp-14h]  
00D7B93D  push        eax  
00D7B93E  push        offset string "%s" (0D818D4h)  
00D7B943  call        dword ptr [__imp__scanf (0D89684h)]
```

You'll have to debug to see what is actually on the stack at this point, e.g. if you are compiling in debug, it is highly likely there's a lot more on the stack than you may think !

Comment: I'm watching the tuts in securitytube about buffer overflows, I have do every thing step by step, and haven't worked. Is there something in the kernel that I have to stop because I haven't disable anything.

Comment: The problem is in how your C code is compiled, the example assumes a simple stack structure and func() being called - but this may not be the case, the compiler may have inlined func(), added stack checks etc. You really have to look at the assembler output to see what is going on.